# google analytics and static subdomain

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, subdomain

First of all: it's not the same as [similiar, but without www prefix problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284384/google-analytics-cookies-vs-subdomain-for-static-content).

I have a website example.com (once again, no "www." prefix). I'd like to serve static content from subdomain static.example.com but Google Analytics keeps to send cookies from static subdomain.

I used a simple CNAME to make subdomain, and here's the Analytics snippet code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX-XX']);       
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']); 
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

I tried setting `_setDomainName` to `example.com` and `none` as above but it doesn't work. I also made a new static subdomain (static2.example.com etc) on each time but it didn't work also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your static subdomain free from GA cookies you should tell GA not to set cookies on the root domain for your site. If you used the www subdomain and set DomainName to that one it should work fine. Since you can't manage to do that, setting cookies for example.com (no www) will assign that cookie to the master domain and they'll be forwarded to any subdomain.

The solutions for you are:

1. Use a subdomain for your content. (www or anything else), and set that full domain on _setDomainName
2. Register a new root domain for your static content. Something like staticexample.com