# How to make google analytics track only domain without subomains?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, subdomain

I have two websites:

1. site.com
2. sub.site.com

First one has google analytics and the cookies have this domain: ".site.com". What happens is that my second site get these cookies posted which is not connected at all and I don't want that. Is there a way to achieve this? I think that changing ".site.com" domain, to "site.com" will work, but I am not 100% sure nor do I know how to do this with google analytics either.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1286792/1671558) in another question, that is not the accepted one though.

We need to add this to the GA code:

```
pageTracker._setDomainName("none")
```

This will set the cookie domain to "site.com" instead of ".site.com" and it will not be posted to subdomains.

Comment: This will do nothing with the current version of Google Analytics (except possibly throwing an js error).

Comment: Not sure about the "current" one, but it works with the version that we use at least :)

Comment: Current Version is Universal Analytics. The code version that supports above snippet is deprecated and does not support all recent features (no custom metrics and dimensions,  no enhanced e-commerce etc).

Comment: @EikePierstorff ga.js is a legacy library are you sure its deprecated?